# Trying to add child type arrays into parent type 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

Basically, i have been trying to build a 2D array which holds arrays of various children classes that all extend the same parent class. Parent Class in question here is GameElement with Rock, RockMoving, Powerups, Enemy and PlayerCharacter all extending GameElement.

```
public class GameWorld implements Serializable {
private static GameWorld gameWorld = new GameWorld();


private Array<Array<GameElement>> gameElementsArray = new Array<Array<GameElement>>();
private PlayerCharacter playerCharacter;
private Array<Rock> rocks;
private Array<RockMoving> rocksMoving;
private Array<Enemy> enemyArray;
private Array<Powerups> powerups;

private Vector2 backgroundPos1, backgroundPos2;

public static GameWorld getInstance() {
    return gameWorld;
}

private GameWorld() {
    gameElementsArray.add(rocks);
    gameElementsArray.add(rocksMoving);
    gameElementsArray.add(powerups);
    gameElementsArray.add(enemyArray);
}

}
```

Problem is, i get

```
add(com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array<com.mygdx.game.sprites.GameElement>)
in Array cannot be applied to
(com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array<com.mygdx.game.sprites.enemies.Enemy>)
```

error in response. We are using libgdx's own array library(which i am slowly growing to hate.).

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of Java's annoying generics. You can give the main array a type of `? extends GameElement`, so the declaration would be:

```
private Array<Array<? extends GameElement>> gameElementsArray = new Array<Array<? extends GameElement>>();
```

This allows any array with types that extend `GameElement` to be added to the array (you can even add arrays with a type of just `GameElement`).

PS: If you hate arrays so much, why not use Java's lists?

Comment: You'd have the same syntax limitations with Java Lists anyway.

Comment: Because i am working with a group. And they want to use libgdx's own arrays. Thank you btw, your answer was really useful.

Comment: A quick follow-up question, is there way to do this for a enhanced loop so it can process this 2D array? Because inner for loop for that requires and Object type and refuses GameElement type. It doesn't allow me to use this  `(GameElement ge : arr)`.

Comment: @BerkErzin The only way is to do this: `for (Array<? extends GameElement> arr : gameElementsArray) { for (GameElement ge : arr) { //code } }`

Comment: @user5074736 That works. (gameElementsArray.get(arrayNum)).addAll(ge);   Problem is that now this line refuses to work. Here arrayNum is int GameElement... ge is the other parameter. It gives a "Cannot resolve method addAll" error. My apologies for bothering you piecemeal like this.